# How to unit test this controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm using the RedirectToAction method to redirect the user to another form after he has filled in the registration form and all the validation has been passed. The only problem occurs during testing the controller. How should I test that the user has been successfully redirected to the required form?

The controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(ClientViewModel clientViewModel)
{ 
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       //filling db object 
                if (license.HasValue)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("RegisterSuccess");
                } 
    }
    return View(clientViewModel);
}
```

The test method:

```
public void Register_WithUniqueUsernameAndEmail_ReturnsRegistrationSuccessful()
{
    // Arrange:
    var mock = new Mock<IAccountFacade>();
    mock.Setup(/*mocking methods*/);
    var controller = new AccountController(mock.Object);
    var context = new ControllerContext();
    var fakeClientViewModel = new ClientViewModel

    // Act:
    var result = controller.Register(fakeClientViewModel);
    // how do I get the name of result or something similar?

    // Assert: ???
}
```

I'm using Moq and Nunit for the testing. If the controller just returned a View I think I would have no problem, but with the RedirectToAction method, I can't find a way to access the actual url or route of the redirect form. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast your `result` variable to the type returned by `RedirectToAction`, which is `RedirectToRouteResult`. Then you can unit test it as follows:

```
var result = (RedirectToRouteResult)controller.Register(fakeClientViewModel);

Assert.AreEqual("ExpectedActionName", result.RouteValues["action"]);
Assert.AreEqual("ExpectedControllerName", result.RouteValues["controller"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't reflect the controller / action, however the test assertions would look something like this:

```
// act
var result = someController.SomeAction() as RedirectToRouteResult;

// assert
Assert.AreEqual("ExpectedRoute", result.RouteValues["action"]);
Assert.AreEqual("ExpectedController", result.RouteValues["controller"]);
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, and sorry, I believe that the edited code is a little bit more clear. Actually when I use the as keyword the result is null, no idea why...